# Configuring external elasticsearch server with IBM MobileFirst Analytics

Tags: elasticsearch, ibm-mobilefirst, analytics, mobilefirst-analytics

By default, MobileFirst Analytics comes with an in-built elasticsearch. I would like to know if there is a way, i can use an elastic search cluster configured on a different host and point it to the MobileFirst Analytics (instead of using the out-of-box one)

I found an article in the [Knowledge center to add a stand-alone elasticsearch node](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.analytics.doc/analytics/t_adding_standalone_ES_node_to_cluster.html), but i couldn't see where to set the host details of the external elasticsearch.

Please advice.Thank you.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your question. Do you want to use MobileFirst Analytics with an additional elasticsearch cluster? or do you only want to use elasticsearch (No MobileFirst Analytics)?

Comment: MF Analytics internally uses elasticsearch. My question is how to configure the MF Analytics to point to an elasticsearch running on a different host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want MobileFirst Platform Analytics to join a cluster with a machine in a different host name then you need to indicate where that Eleasticsearch instance is. You can specify that as a JNDI property

`<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts" value="['yourotherhost:port','otherhost:otherport']" />`

Operational Analytics Properties and configurations:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_properties.html

For more info on ES network configurations:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#common-network-settings